# In Elasticsearch, how to search in another index from to match value from response of same query and get combine response

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk

I have two indices i.e. asset and mediaobject respectively, asset is a parent index of mediaobject and mediaobject contains nested field metadata. Mediaobject have field named "asset" which contains value of "id" field from asset index, this is how they are linked. When I search for in value from metadata field the result should contains that field with parent document which is a mediaobject document and grandparent document which is asset document.
Result should look like this
search*term:"metadata_name*"
{
{
asset*id:"qwerty",

"asset*_*name:"asset1",

other fields of asset....

},

{

mediaobjectid:"asdf",

mediaobjectname

asset:"qwerty",

metadata:[

"field*1*":"metadata_name"*

]
}

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metadata",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "image"
        }      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subquery_mock": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "params": {
          "disallowed_msg": "OUT Followup Synthesis"
        }, 
        "init_script": "state.by_asset_ids = [:]; ",
        "map_script": """
          def asset_id = params._source.asset;
          
          if (state.by_asset_ids.containsKey(asset)) {
            state.by_assets[asset].add(params._source);
          } else {
            state.by_assets[asset] = [params._source];
          }
        """return state.by_assets
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```